# Storing files on file-system when there are multiple server instances

Tags: django, blob, filefield, file-storage

I have multiple django server instances handled by a load balancer.
When I need to scale up, I replicate a clone of the server machine and add the new server instance to the load balancer.

I also use the admin interface in order to upload configuration files, which are stored localy using FileFields.
This raises a problem, because the server instances become stateful and don't all share the same files.

This is what I'm asking:

- What would be the correct way for storing files that need to be accessed from multiple servers?
- Is storing the files in the DB a good idea?
- Perhaps upload to S3?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, the most widely used approach is to use one of the network file systems, such as:

- [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System)
- [CIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIFS)
- etc, etc

If you want to use Amazon S3 to store your files, take a look at [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) project, it allows you to mount remote S3 bucket as local folder on your servers.